# Exchange 2010 Mail stuck in Queue

Tags: exchange-2010

Yesterday we got hit by a barrage of spam around 250/Min and caused our exchange queues to go a bit spazzy (in a technical sense) I stopped mail at our External relay so we could get this back under control. Once the exchange server stabilised and I had killed most of the spam at the relay I allow mail to flow again (and its working finer now) But my issue is that:

I have noticed that there are 110 messages stuck in the `Submission queue` in a Suspended state and a few in retry state. These are all spam messages but when I try and remove them the tool does not appear in the GUI. I can use the `Get-Queue` power shell command to see the queues but when I try and drill down I cannot get into the Submission queue only our SMTP connector.

This is Exchange 2010 SP2,

---

**EDIT:**

When I view the Queues I get the below

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>get-queue

Identity                                    DeliveryType Status MessageCount NextHopDomain
--------                                    ------------ ------ ------------ -------------
EXCHANGE1\234                               MapiDelivery Ready  0            mainstore
EXCHANGE1\242                               SmartHost... Ready  0            smtp.***local
EXCHANGE1\Submission                        Undefined    Ready  109          Submission
```

I have retried my Powershell and below is the output.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Retry-Queue Submission -Resubmit $true
The requested operation can't be performed for the object with identity Submission
```

.

Comment: So, what's the problem?  You can't remove the stuck spam in the GUI?  Or in Powershell?  Or both?

Comment: Both, sorry I wasnt clear. When I powershell it dossnt return an error, but it dose not diaply the queue.

Comment: Run `repadmin /syncall /AdeP` on your domain controllers if this happens before you are doing a ton of other stuff and give it a good few minutes afterwards. Be sure to run this command on all your domain controllers to. Additionally if you run on your DCs do it in order one by one, then reverse and run the command in reverse order to ensure you run on each DC twice. Give the replication time to sync afterwards but if you have fast DC link, then it should not take too long depending on your number of DCs. For 8 across sites of fast links, 5 minutes should be plenty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue fixed with the first resource

First resources:
[Some e-mail messages become stuck in an Exchange Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979175)

Second resources :
[About the Poison Message Queue and the Unreachable Queue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125022.aspx)

Comment: it was a combnation of this and re-creating the queues.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure dont do not want the mail that is stuck in the queue then can create a new queue

http://www.techieshelp.com/exchange-2007-and-exchange-2010-create-new-mail-queu-database/